# Bootstrap menu is not pushing down the content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please pardon my ignorance, I am new to bootstrap. I have this code that I need to correct, and I can't figure out why the menu is not pushing the rest of the content down on click. Here are the HTML and CSS Code snippets

```css
*:before,
   *:after {
     box-sizing: border-box;
   }
   .navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
     border-color: #ddd;
   }
   .navbar-toggle {
     background-color: transparent;
     background-image: none;
     border: 1px solid transparent;
     border-radius: 4px;
     float: right;
     margin-bottom: 8px;
     margin-right: 15px;
     margin-top: 8px;
     padding: 9px 10px;
     position: relative;
   }
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle" type="button" aria-expanded="true">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
            <img alt="Harbor Real Estate" src="img/logo.png">
          </a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" class="navbar-collapse collapse in" aria-expanded="true" style="">

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Buy</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Rent</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Landlords</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Property Management</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
      <!-- /container-fluid -->
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

I had similar problem and found that it was due to setting a fixed height to the header tag which contains my navbar.

I fixed it by placing that particular CSS in a media query so it only applied to larger screens.

Comment: Fixed it for me. I had max-height on desktop view-port width and height in media queries, should have used padding and or margin instead. Thanks. You've saved me a hour or two troubleshooting that.

Answer (score 3):

I think it does push your content downwards see my example below.

I've changed the code in your question into a code snippet and added jQuery and Bootstrap's CSS and JavaScript. As the collapsing behaviour of the navbar is dependent on jQuery and Bootstrap's JavaScript perhaps that was missing.

Two additional things:

1. I've removed the class `in` from the `<div id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" ...` to make the navbar be collapsed by default
2. I've removed the outer `.row` and `.col-md-12` as they aren't needed

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle" type="button" aria-expanded="true">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
        <img alt="Harbor Real Estate" src="img/logo.png">
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" class="navbar-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="true" style="">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Buy</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Rent</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Landlords</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Property Management</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /container-fluid -->
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add main j-query.
jquery-1.11.1.min.js

In Your code to work this menu

Answer (score 0):

Muhammad Hasham. Try this! Works.

```
<head>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle" type="button" aria-expanded="true">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
                                <img alt="Harbor Real Estate" src="img/logo.png">
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                        <div id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" class="navbar-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="true">

                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Buy</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Rent</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Landlords</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Property Management</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /navbar-collapse -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /container-fluid -->
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```